# Staged roll out and beta testers on Android

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

For our Android app, we have a number of beta testers signed up via an opt-in link through Google Play. If I do a staged production roll out at 10%, will that include my beta testers or will they just have to be the lucky 10% to get it?

Is there a way that I can publish a version of the app both to beta testers and to 10% as staged roll out at the same time through Google Play?

Basically I want to release to a few specific users (beta testers) as well as to a % of the rest of users, before going to prod at 100%.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Basically I want to release to a few specific users (beta testers) as well as to a % of the rest of users, before going to prod at 100%.

I don't think you'll be able to do that. An app is either in alpha, in beta, or in production. It can not be more than one simultaneously.

You cannot distribute an APK both as beta as well as production app.

Answer (score 2):

Beta testers are implicitly included in a staged rollout. Otherwise, the beta release would be lagging behind the production release, and that really shouldn't happen.

My own empirical observations confirm this: I've done several staged rollouts, and beta testers have always been among the first to receive the update.

Of course it's also possible to release to beta first, and then promote the APK to production with a staged rollout.